# Loop not working on custom front page

Tags: wordpress

Instead of using index.php as my front page, I've created a custom page and changed the "Front page displays" setting in the "Reading Settings" tab accordingly.

Loops don't seem to be working with my custom front page, although they still work on index.php.

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<--- POST CONTENT -->
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php else : ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

What might I be doing wrong? Is there some other bit of code I need to include?

UPDATE:

To clarify, I need for the home page to be a custom page because I'm using custom fields so the client can edit bits of content easily enough. This is why I'm not using index.php or home.php

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to make a custom homepage you can create a home.php and this will be used instead.

If you are using more than 1 loop make sure your reset the loop.

Comment: To clarify, I need for the home page to be a custom page because I'm using custom fields so the client can edit bits of content easily enough. This is why I'm not using index.php or home.php

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you need to tell the loop what it has to show in page templates.

So simply use a custom query in that custom page like this:

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status'=>'publish',
    'posts_per_page'=> get_option('posts_per_page'),
    'paged' => $paged,
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC' 
    );

    $wp_query=new WP_Query($args);
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
      ...
    endwhile;
```